# Residue ${{(z+1)^2}\sin(1/z)}\over{(3z+1)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Calculate residue at $z=0$ of $\dfrac{{(z+1)^2\sin(1/z)}}{(3z+1)^2}$

It is essential singularity.So I am trying to get Laurent series expansion.Which in this case is hard because requires combing two expansions.

Comment: Are you able to get it in the form of an infinite series?

Comment: Speculation: You seem to know the Laurent series for $\sin(1/z)$. Use long division on $(z+1)^2/(3z+1)^2$ to simplify, then the remainder can be put into an infinite series. Now you can find the coefficient of $1/z$ by multiplying and adding the appropriate terms.

Comment: Oh, I did not think about division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with the residue at infinity, you can reduce your problem to a simpler one. Set
$$ f(z) = \left( \frac{z+1}{3z+1} \right)^2 \sin \left( \frac{1}{z} \right). $$

The function $f$ has isolated singularities at $z = 0, -\frac{1}{3}, \infty$. Let us calculate the residue at infinity first. We have

$$ -\frac{1}{z^2} f \left( \frac{1}{z} \right) = -\frac{1}{z^2} \left( \frac{\frac{1}{z}  + 1}{\frac{3}{z} + 1} \right)^2 \sin(z) = -\frac{1}{z^2} \left( \frac{1+z}{3 + z} \right)^2 \sin(z). $$

Since $\left( \frac{1+z}{3+z} \right)^2 \sin(z)$ is holomorphic at $z = 0$, we see that the residue at infinity is zero. Since the total sum of residues is always zero, we have

$$ \operatorname{Res}(f, 0) = -\operatorname{Res} \left( f, -\frac{1}{3} 
\right) $$

so it is enough to calculate $\operatorname{Res} \left( f, -\frac{1}{3} 
\right)$. We have

$$ f(z) = \frac{(z+1)^2}{9} \sin \left( \frac{1}{z} \right) \frac{1}{ \left( z + \frac{1}{3} \right)^2} = \frac{g(z)}{\left( z + \frac{1}{3} \right)^2}$$

for $g$ which is holomorphic at $z = -\frac{1}{3}$. Hence, the residue $\operatorname{Res} \left( f, -\frac{1}{3} 
\right)$ will be $g' \left( -\frac{1}{3} \right)$ which can be calculated directly.

Comment: If f(1/z) is holomorphic near z=0, does f(z) have to be holomorphic in the neighbourhood of infinity?

Comment: @user399523: That's the definition. A function $f$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of infinity if it is defined and holomorphic on $|z| > R$ for some $R$. This is equivalent to saying that $f \left( \frac{1}{z} \right)$ is defined an holomorphic on $0 < |z| < \frac{1}{R}$.

Comment: What about g(z)=1/z . g(1/z) = z is holomorphic. But Res of g(z) at infinity is -1

Comment: How do I know that this case is different.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The residue at infinity of $g$ is not the residue of $g \left( \frac{1}{z} \right)$ at $z = 0$ but of $-\frac{1}{z^2} g \left( \frac{1}{z} \right)$. In your case, it is $-1$. One of the reasons the residue at infinity is defined this way is to make the theorem that says that the sum of all residues is zero hold.

Comment: Ok, now I finally see it.